# Privilege issue while executing the command over Robotframework SSH

Tags: python, ssh, cygwin, robotframework, paramiko

I am trying to execute command to create DB in the remote machine using Robotframework SSH which will throw an privileged error. But if I try to run same command over PUTTY application or using Paramiko library it will work seamless. How can I fix this issue?

Firstly I tried to execute command directly through putty application and it is executing properly. But when I execute in python Shell using SSHLibrary it will throw following error.

```
from SSHLibrary import SSHLibrary # library from Robotframework
ob=SSHLibrary()
ob.open_connection("192.168.5.10")
ob.login("Administrator","Password")
print ob.execute_command("db2 create db test7")
```

Output will be::

```
u'SQL1092N  The requested command or operation failed because the user ID 
does \r\r\nnot have the authority to perform the requested command or 
operation.  User \r\r\nID: "LOCAL SERVICE".\r\r'
```

If I execute this above command directly using paramiko library it will successfully create database
This is the working code :

```
import paramiko
c=paramiko.Transport(('192.168.5.10',22))
c.connect(username='Administrator',password='Password')
sess=c.open_channel(kind='session')
sess.exec_command('db2 create db test7')
print sess.recv(4096)
```

output will be:

```
DB20000I  The CREATE DATABASE command completed successfully.
```

Though **SSHLibrary internally dependent on paramiko** library it self, it fails to execute the command. But if I use paramiko library directly it will execute properly as like putty application. I wonder how its not working from Robot SSHLibrary. Someone please help me in fixing this issue...

Note: *remote machine is windows with cygwin installed to enable SSH!*

Comment: I believe the difference is that others has a "terminal session" and the SSHLibrary one doesn't, and Cygwin runs the command using a wrong user for the cases where there is no terminal session.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala is there any resolution??

Comment: IDK. I've never used Robot Framework, and Cygwin SSH last time more than a decade ago IIRC. I've just got a hunch there^

Comment: @AnttiHaapala thanks alot for leaving a hint about  **session**